# E,F banach space, T $\in$ K(E,F) dim E= $\infty$ show R(T) is closed

Tags: functional-analysis

I was confuse about how to prove this ~~
My thought is prove the N(T) is finite dimension first 
then use this property to get R(T) is closed

Comment: What is $K(E,F)$?

Comment: I forgot to add one more assmption ~~~ it is bounded below

I know how to prove it ~~ thx for answer

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong. $T:\ell^2\to\ell^2$, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N} \mapsto (x_n/n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is compact with dense range.